# wheels of mobile 4 wheel robot tilt in gazebo when trying to rotate about its axis

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The joints in the robot are **continuous**. but when the robot tries to change its yaw, the wheel joints deform as if due to friction the robot is not able to rotate. I tried to change the link mass and friction values but no effect. I don't understand why the joints ane not stiff. [problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzzbW.png) This image shows the problem.

If anyone faced this kind of problem earlier, please help.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341511/wheels-of-mobile-4-wheel-robot-tilt-in-gazebo-when-trying-to-rotate-about-its-axis./) by [prabin_rath](https://answers.ros.org/users/50841/prabin_rath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2020-01-11

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hermansiak](https://answers.ros.org/users/74826/hermansiak/) on 2021-05-19**:
Hi there, I encountered the same problem. Have you found a solution?

**Comment by [amjack](https://answers.ros.org/users/57146/amjack/) on 2022-02-10**:
Hi , Any update on this issue ?

**Comment by [prabin_rath](https://answers.ros.org/users/50841/prabin_rath/) on 2022-02-10**:
Yes, I was able to fix this issue. Sorry for not updating this thread. I have put my solution in the answers, please find it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution to this problem can be found in the updated xacro for this robot at [description file](https://github.com/prabinrath/fist_lab_arm/blob/main/roboarm/urdf/armbot/armbot.urdf.xacro)

```
<dynamics damping="0"/>
```

The property of the joint needs to be mentioned in the robot description to avoid such deformation of joint. I hope that helps.

---

Originally posted by [prabin_rath](https://answers.ros.org/users/50841/prabin_rath/) with karma: 31 on 2022-02-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1